# Nullable check no work when in out variable

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
public Boolean TryGetValue(object Key, out object? O)
{
        return //some logic
}
```

When I use the method like this:

```
TryGetValue("Test", out int? Result);
```

Visual Studio reports an error:

```
cannot convert from 'out int?' to 'out object?'
```

However, in `IMemoryCache.TryGetValue`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache.trygetvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) which is similar to my code.

```
IMemoryCache.TryGetValue("Test", out int? Result);
```

can works without any error.

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: Your `TryGetValue` expects an `out object`. You are giving it an `out int`. Of course it's not going to work. What if `TryGetValue` assigns a `string` to the parameter?

Comment: Note that this will fail just as much with just `object` and `int` - it's not the nullability that makes the difference here. The arguments for `out` parameters have to have the same types (or identity-convertible types, e.g. dynamic vs object) as the parameters themselves.

Comment: The method you have identified is likely the static extension method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.trygetvalue not the interface method you linked.

Comment: The source for the extension method I identified: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L23

Comment: @moreON In spite of the code is not long, it is hard for me to understand it. Let me try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `TryGetValue` on an `IMemoryCache` instance and pass any type other than `object` you're leveraging a generic extension method: [`CacheExtensions.TryGetValue<TItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.trygetvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). That's why it works for `IMemoryCache` and not your method.

Fortunately, we have the source code for that extension [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L23-L42). All it does is call the standard `TryGetValue` method to get an `object` result, then checks if the return value is the right type to fit your output variable.

You can adapt the same method for your own code, or write a generic entry point of your own to handle different types.

Answer (score 0):

`object` is a class type, you need to use a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) instead.